# server side path to filesystem

Tags: 7, files, uri

How do I get the server side directory of the filesystem path?

For example, my files are in http://mydomain.local/myfiles; this is the root of my drupal filesystem. I am searching for a function that will give me d:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\myfiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will get you the d:\xampp\htdocs and `$base_path` or `base_path()` will give you the Drupal part.

Comment: The above should work for what you're trying to do.  drupal_realpath() is great if you have a stream URI.

Comment: The $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] has value "d:\xampp\htdocs\drupal". The base_path() has value "/". **I am still missing the "myfiles"** which you specify in Drupal in admin/config/media/file-system. For drupal_realpath(), the documentation says that "This function is deprecated, and should be removed wherever possible". Does this function have a replacement, then?

Comment: check out `variable_get('file_public_path', '')`

Comment: Thanks! I was starting to look into things like DrupalPublicStreamWrapper, which are a bit complicated to me, but the variable file_public_path is the missing piece.